# How to reference foreign key which does not reference a primary key column. Asp.net mvc code first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have given reference of one of my columns (which is not the primary key) as foreign key in another table. But I'm not sure how to deal with it in Entity Framework. I have specific reason that I can not user my primary key as foreign key column in reference table.

```
public class Users : IUser
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(64)]
    [Column("USERID")]
    public string USERID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    [Column("PASSWORD")]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public byte[] PASSWORD { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2)]
    public string STATUS { get; set; }

    [Column("UserIdentifierId")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class RolesUsers
{
    [Key]
    public int RolesUsersId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual Roles Role { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see `UserIdentifierId` is my column which I have configured as reference for `UserId` in `RolesUsers` table (in SQL `UserIdentifierId` is unique constraint which is valid for reference)

I am getting following error at moment:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: RolesUsers_User_Target_RolesUsers_User_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'UserId' on entity 'RolesUsers' does not match the type of property 'USERID' on entity 'Users' in the referential constraint 'RolesUsers_User'.

SQL structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ATQ_USERS]
(
    [USERID] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [PASSWORD] [varbinary](64) NULL,
    [STATUS] [char](2) NULL,
    [UserIdentifierId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ATQ_USERS] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([USERID] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY],
    CONSTRAINT [Uk_UserIdentifierId] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([UserIdentifierId] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Roles]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOnUTC] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedOnUTC] [datetime] NULL,
    [DeletedOnUTC] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Text] [varchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Roles] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RolesUsers]
(
    [RolesUsersId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [int] NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RolesUsersId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RolesUsers] WITH CHECK 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Roles] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RolesUsers] WITH CHECK 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ATQ_USERS] ([UserIdentifierId])
```

Comment: can u share db script ?

Comment: It's not possible in pre EF Core. Any special reason identity column not be PK and the string - unique (the opposite of what they are currently)?

Comment: check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, i have some limitation as I am using existing Db to migrate one more application as per given requirement,

Comment: Then EF Core is the only option. But it has other (and lot more) issues :(

Comment: There should be no integrity constraints in EF ATM (at least what I'm aware of). Maybe the .Join function can handle that, if not you'll most likely have to join in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem.  Just declare UserIdentifierId to be the entity Key.  There's nothing magical about which key is declared as the PK in the database.  Your Entity can use any Unique Index as the key.

Comment: Only if 1. this is not code-first with migrations and 2. any other entities referring to `User` use the same foreign key.